# Spring MVC Front End Validations

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, validation, frameworks, frontend

I wanted to validate user inputs in my jsp which were binded to Springformdata objects using `<spring:bind>` without hitting the controller.

Is there any other way I can achive this in spring MVC without using javascrpit.

See below code

```
<tr><td>
                        <spring:bind path="applyDmlFormData.file">
                            Select DML File : <input type="file" name="file"/> 
                        </spring:bind>
                    </td></tr>
```

Here I am asking user to browse/select the input file and then attaching that to applyDmlFormData objects' file property.

If user don't selects any file and submits the form I wanted to validate that in the forntend itself without hitting the controller and display a error message saying file must me choosen. Basically I wanted to achieve the same functionality which is available in struts validation framework.

One more thing to add is I dont want to use validator which will be invoked by controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/applyDml.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String process(@ModelAttribute("applyDmlFormData") ApplyDmlFormData applyDmlFormData, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        String mav = applyDmls;
        validator.validate(applyDmlFormData, result);

        if(!result.hasErrors())
        { //Business logic goes here
        }
    }
```

In the above code I am validating user inputs using validator.validate I dont want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The Struts Validator framework generates client-side JavaScript; AFAIK, Spring MVC doesn't offer a similar functionality.  You need to roll your own client-side validation code.  Even if you include Spring JS in your application, you still need to write your own validation code; [here's an example](http://www.earldouglas.com/barebones-spring-mvc/rich-client-validation/).

Note that you don't need to use use a `Validator` object in your handler methods.  You can also annotate your `@ModelAttribute` with `@Valid` and use JSR-303 annotations.  See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-beanvalidation-overview for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can explore the [Rhino library](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)..find the spring integration api [here](http://rhinoinspring.sourceforge.net/)